# (C++11) Variadically templated function fowards to another

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to forward my tail from `parser` to `add_option`, but GCC won't allow this:

```
// Templated constructor
template <typename H = std::string, typename... T>
parser(H head, T... tail) {
    /* Add an option */
    add_option(std::forward<T>(tail)...);
}

// Base case
void add_option(std::string head) {
    /* Add an option */
}

// Recursive case
template <typename H = std::string, typename... T>
void add_option(H head, T... tail) {
    add_option(tail...);
}
```

Instead, GCC gives me this error:

```
parser.h: In instantiation of ‘void parser::add_option(H, T ...) [with H = const char*; T = {}]’:
parser.h:16:4:   required from ‘parser::parser(H, T ...) [with H = const char*; T = {const char*}]’
parser.cpp:7:26:   required from here
parser.h:24:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘parser::add_option()’
    add_option(tail...);
    ^
parser.h:24:4: note: candidates are:
parser.h:18:8: note: void parser::add_option(std::string)
   void add_option(std::string head) {
        ^
parser.h:18:8: note:   c1andidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
parser.h:22:8: note: template<class H, class ... T> void parser::add_option(H, T ...)
   void add_option(H head, T... tail) {
        ^
parser.h:22:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
parser.h:24:4: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
    add_option(tail...);
    ^
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'parser' failed
make: *** [parser] Error 1
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here? How can I fix this?

Comment: try this: void add_option() {}

Comment: you have strict `std::string` parameter requirements in both `add_option`s, yet you pass them only generic type `T` arguments recursively.

Comment: You expect `add_option(string)` to terminate the recursion - but the actual parameter you pass is `const char*`, not `string`, and the templated `add_option<const char*>` is a better match.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Your advice worked. If you can expand this into an 
answer, I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: My advice? But I didn't actually suggest anything. I just tried to explain the behavior you were seeing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well, as far as I'm concerned, you implied that `add_option<const char*>` is a better match; and it is. Exchanging the template signature of `std::string` with `const char*` did the trick. :)

Comment: @Chiru that's dependent on how you call `parser`. If that fixed your problem, it sounds like you aren't really making use of templates anyways.

Comment: When you get an error, including the line in your source code where the error occurs (in particual, `add_option("foo")` is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct parser {
  template <typename... Ts>
  parser(std::string head, Ts... ts) {
    add_options(std::move(head), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }

  // Base case
  void add_options(std::string head) {
    // I assume we store head somewhere.  `std::move` from it
    // if we don't directly store it, replace all std::string with std::string const&
    std::cout << "option: " << head.c_str() << "\n";
  }

  // Recursive case.  Make 2+ arguments explicit (probably not needed, but I like it)
  template <typename T0, typename... Ts>
  void add_options(std::string head, T0&& t0, Ts&&... ts) {
    add_options(std::move(head));
    add_options(std::forward<T0>(t0), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
};

int main() {
  parser parse("hello", "world");
}
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/lotY20)

Comment: Although I'm not sure about why the question was downvoted, I really like your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chiru If your parser can only take a variable number of string arguments, you should use a `va_list`. Variadic templates are overkill when you know the type in advance.

Comment: @chiru no, use `std::initializer_list<std::string>` not C style varargs.

Comment: @redalert no, do not use C style variardics, not casually at least.

Comment: @Yakk To be honest, my only reason to choose variadics over `std::initializer_list<std::string>` in the first place (be it templated or not) was to reduce the outstanding ugliness when calling functions, because `std::initializer_list<std::string>` requires curly brackets around the argument as far as I know.